# How to restrict user from submitting a form twice in sharepoint?

Tags: form, user-controls, edit

I'm working on a sharepoint forms

And I need to block edition for users after they submitted a due date (data format), but I don't know if sharepoint allows it

Someone knows how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. When you say "block edition", do you mean "block editing"?

If you don't want users to edit an item after it has been created, you can create a validation formula that will not allow edits after "x" minutes. The example below will not allow edits after one minute.

```
=Created <= NOW()+1/24/60
```

(1 day / 24 hours / 60 minutes)

To add this to your list:

- Go to the list's properties page.
- Click Validation settings.
- Enter the above formula.
- Enter an error message.